# How can the ending of "Sympathy for Mr. Vengeance" be explained?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, sympathy-for-mr-vengeance

In the end of the movie [Sympathy for Mr. Vengeance](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0310775/combined), Park Dong-jin get's killed by the group of communists, that Yeong-mi is member of. But earlier in the movie it is explained, that Yeong-mi is the only member of this group. So why do they show up in the end? Was it simply a mistake of the inspector, who earlier stated they wouldn't exist?

Answer (score 3):

Although it is true that Dong-jin is not part of the same organization (communists? terrorists?), it is worth remembering that Ryu's girlfriend, Yeong-mi, is.

When Dong-jin captures Yeong-mi and interrogates her to find out what happened to his daughter, Yeong-mi explains that she belongs to the same group, and that if he should harm her, the group would track him down and kill him.

True to her word, once Dong-jin has killed her through electrocution, the organization does indeed hunt him down and stab him to death.

So, the connection was not through his daughter, but through Ryu's girlfriend.

Comment: But the inspector said earlier she is the only member of that organization (so there is in reality no organization).

Comment: Could it just be a mistake on the inspector's part through lack of facts?

Comment: Maybe, but it seemed strange. At the part the police is talking about talking her being member in the group, the first order was to arrest all members for interrogation. But they say at this moment, they already would've done this, but she is the only member. Can't remember details though, I have to rewatch it. But it seems unlikely only an error, they wouldn't have given up so fast, because they have a major crime with taking a girl hostage.